# Vuex - modifying local copy of state causes mutation error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've come across an issue in my Vue app that I can't explain. I am getting the following error when attempting to update a local copy of a piece of state.

> Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

Here's a sample of what I'm doing in my code

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: 'sampleComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            userModel: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.userModel = this.user
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getApplicationUsers']),
        user() {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getApplicationUsers[0]))
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addUserRole() {
            if (!this.userModel.userRoles.includes("newRole")) {
                this.userModel.userRoles.push("newRole")
            }
        }
        removeUserRole() {
            let index = this.userModel.userRoles.indexOf("newRole");
            if (index > -1) {
                this.userModel.userRoles.splice(index, 1)
            }
        }
}
```

Whenever removeUserRole is called, I get the mutation error. I can add roles just fine with addUserRole, but it yells at me when I try to remove a role.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? When I deep copy the piece of state, shouldn't`userModel` now be decoupled from the state, unwatched by vuex, and mutable?

Comment: This code looks fine, there must be some other code that is mutating the state. Did you accidentally commit any sub object of `objectModel` to the Vuex state?

Comment: Where is `objectModel` defined? Shouldn't it be in `data`? Also, if this is a component, `data` should be a function

Comment: Phil - You're right. I'll update the question. I was free hand copying this and mistyped data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decade Moon's first comment led me to the answer. I successfully created a mutable object with JSON.parse/JSON.stringify, but then elsewhere in my code I was committing that object up to a temporary holding place in the store. When I later tried to mutate my local object, there was a reference to it in the store which caused the mutation error to be thrown.

The reason why my first action didn't cause an error is because I hadn't committed the userModel to the store at that point. Once userModel was committed to the store, obviously, it then began throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code...

1. In a component, `data` should be a function
2. You need to initialise all your component properties in `data`, otherwise they won't be reactive
3. If you want to create a local copy of a state property, do so in `data`

With all that in mind, try this

```
data () {
  return {
    objectModel: {...this.$store.getters.getApplicationUsers[0]}
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the typo in the code in my question; good catch. I tried pulling the initialization out of the mounted hook and put it straight in data like you suggested, but the behavior is the same. Interestingly, attempting to create a mutable copy of the state with the spread operator and Object.assign cause both my functions to throw the mutation error, while JSON.parse/JSON.strigify makes it so only the removal function throws the mutation error